# how to handle this error generated in doing sicp exercise 4.9?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I am doing the exercise.4.9 of the sicp and I am trying to implement a syntax of the "for statement" which looks like the others would see in the c++:

```
(for (((i 0) (j 1))
      (< (+ i j) 10)
      ((i (+ i 1))))
     (display "i:")
     (display i)
     (display "\n")
     (display "j:")
     (display j)
     (display "\n"))
```

the syntax looks like:

```
(for ((initial-statement) (predicate-statement) (updating-statement)) (for-body))
```

and what I have generated is like:

```
((lambda ()
   (define j 1)
   (define i 0)
   (define inner-loop
     (if (< (+ i j) 10)
         (begin (display "i:")
                (display i)
                (display "\n")
                (display "j:")
                (display j)
                (display "\n")
                (set! i (+ i 1))
                (inner-loop))))
   (inner-loop)))
```

And I got an error saying that the first `inner-loop` invocation was trying to approach an unbound variable,

I am wondering what does the correct code I should generate look like?

Comment: You are defining a variable INNER-LOOP, but you call it as a function. You need to define a function INNER-LOOP.

Comment: @RainerJoswig  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rainer mentioned in the comments, your definition of `inner-loop` is incorrect.

A function in scheme is defined as: `(define (name ...args) body)`

Or if there are no arguments: `(define (name) body)`

The following works:

```
((lambda ()
   (define j 1)
   (define i 0)
   (define (inner-loop)
     (if (< (+ i j) 10)
         (begin (display "i:")
                (display i)
                (display "\n")
                (display "j:")
                (display j)
                (display "\n")
                (set! i (+ i 1))
                (inner-loop))))
   (inner-loop)))
```